# Como fazer a variável vir pra fora

Tags: angular

Não estou conseguindo trazer a variável para fora do then.

```
  anggota: any;
  ida: number;
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res)=>{
      this.anggota = res;
      this.username = this.anggota.username;
      this.ida = this.anggota.user_id;
      console.log(this.ida);
    });

    console.log(this.ida);
  }
```

No código acima o segundo console.log não está imprimindo o this.ida.

Comment: Sim, não vai conseguir mesmo, **this.storage.get()** é uma **Promise**, ou seja, uma função assíncrona. O segundo log ainda não tem o resultado do retorno da promise!

Answer (score -1):

tente usar `async` e `await`

```js
anggota: any;
ida: number;
async ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.anggota = await this.storage.get('session_storage');
  this.username = this.anggota.username;
  this.ida = this.anggota.user_id;
  console.log(this.ida);
}
```